# How to normalize Kernel Density Estimation using scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I am using KDE for multi-class classification. I am implementing it using scikit.
As mentioned on the website, the KDE for a point x is defined as,
[image]

Should I normalize the result while comparing different kernel density estimates for different classes?

Link for KDE:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density-estimation

Comment: KDE estimates a probability density - if I am not mistaken a density is per definition normed. Not sure why the formula is not normed - IMO the equals does not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equality does not hold, this is clearly a bad documentation example. You can see in the code that it is normalized, like here

```
log_density -= np.log(N)
return log_density
```

so you clearly divide by `N`.

The correct formula, from mathematical perspective is actually either

```
1/N SUM_i K(x_i - x)
```

or

```
1/(hN) SUM_i K((x_i - x)/h)
```

you can also dive [deeper into .c code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/51a765acfa4c5d1ec05fc4b406968ad233c75162/sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.c) actually computing kernels and you will find that they are internally normalized

```
 case __pyx_e_7sklearn_9neighbors_9ball_tree_GAUSSIAN_KERNEL:

 /* "binary_tree.pxi":475
 *     cdef ITYPE_t k
 *     if kernel == GAUSSIAN_KERNEL:
 *         factor = 0.5 * d * LOG_2PI             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     elif kernel == TOPHAT_KERNEL:
 *         factor = logVn(d)
 */
    __pyx_v_factor = ((0.5 * __pyx_v_d) * __pyx_v_7sklearn_9neighbors_9ball_tree_LOG_2PI);
    break;
```

Thus each `K` actually integrates to `1` and consequently you just take an average to get valid density for whole KDE, and this is exactly what happens inside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be clear, I don't need to do anything because it normalizes internally? I can just compare different KDE's?

Comment: Yes, there are normalized. In terms of comparison - it depends what do you want to achieve by such comparison, but in principle yes, they are comparable. If you do classification then no. Classification should include prior over classes too, KDE is just generative model, thus you have to add weight proportional to class size to have accuracy based model. If you do not add this you do "balanced" accuracy